# Water-based vs oil-based primers: longevity in a hot, dry desert

Tags: paint, exterior

How does the longevity compare between water-based and oil-based primers in a hot, dry desert (i.e. 100º-110ºF) on wood (e.g. eaves of house) in terms of chipping/peeling/coming off?

Are there any factors that are particularly important or unimportant? Thickness (thin layer vs thick layer vs multiple thin layers)? Cost (expensive vs. cheap)? Application method (roller vs HVLP)? Treatment (full cleaning & sanding vs simply removing existing peeling paint/primer)?